# Not able to use java.util.Duration as @Value configuration in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

We are not able to use java.util.Duration as @Value configuration in Spring Boot.

Sample project that exhibits this problem here: https://github.com/costimuraru/spring-boot-sample
Spring Boot version: 1.5.9.RELEASE

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Value("${mykey}")
    Duration value;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings at " + value;
    }

}

...

public class MyConfigPropertySource extends PropertySource {

    MyConfigPropertySource(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String path) {
        return "mykey".equals(path) ? Duration.ofMinutes(1) : null;
    }
}
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'helloController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type [java.time.Duration]
>   to type [java.lang.String]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]

This error is totally unexpected: `No converter found capable of converting from type [java.time.Duration] to type [java.lang.String]`. We are not using String in neither the @Value field nor in the return statement from the PropertySource. So why is Spring Boot trying to convert it to String? Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Before anyone wastes their time trying to answer this, it's also been asked and answered on Spring Boot's issue tracker: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11306. Please don't cross-post like this.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I can't tell the number of times I've hit stackoverflow *first* that linked to spring database issues, I don't find this cross-posting at all... I even would suggest you answer your comment with an answer- so people do know where to look.

Comment: First comment in the linked issue : Thanks for getting in touch, but it feels like this is a question that would be better suited to Stack Overflow. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just use Spring Expression Language

```
@Value("#{T(java.time.Duration).parse('${mykey}')}")
private Duration value;
```